# how send Post request with ajax in ember.js?

Tags: forms, ember.js, authentication

I want to send a POST (not GET) request to the server with ember.js. I don't know which function I need at **"which function here"**, but I want to send it to the server for a login request.

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    userLogin: function(user) {
      // which function here? 
      ?? ("http://siteurl/api/authentication/login/&username=" + user.username + "&password=" + user.password + ""); 
      this.transitionTo('cat');

    },

    cancelLogin: function() {
      this.transitionTo('menu');
    }
  }
});

App.UserFormComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    submit: function() {
      this.sendAction('submit', {
        username: this.get('username'),
        password: this.get('password')
      });
    },

    cancel: function() {
      this.sendAction('cancel');
    }
  }
});
```

down here template code

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="login">
        <header class="bar bar-nav">
            <h1 class="title">inloggen</h1>
            {{#link-to 'menu' class="icon icon icon-bars pull-right"}}{{/link-to}}
        </header>   
        <!-- SHOW LOADER -->
        <div class="content">  
        <div class="content-padded">
        {{user-form submit="userLogin" cancel="cancelLogin" submitTitle="login"}}
        </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/user-form">
   <form {{action "submit" on="submit"}}>
     <p><label>gebruikersnaam {{input type="text" value=username}}</label></p>
     <p><label>wachtwoord {{input type="password" value=password}}</label></p>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" {{bindAttr value=submitTitle}}>
     <button class="btn btn-negative btn-block" {{action "cancel"}}>Cancel</button>
   </form>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ember doesn't have any built in communication layer, you can use jquery for such calls.

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    userLogin: function(user) {      
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://siteurl/api/authentication/login/&username=" + user.username + "&password=" + user.password,
        data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
      })
      this.transitionTo('cat');

    },

    cancelLogin: function() {
      this.transitionTo('menu');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It's better to use ember-ajax now.

Comment: Yes, ember ajax is a better solution: It is here: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax

Comment: *It's better to use ember-ajax now* Define "better"?

Comment: What's not really mentioned on the ember-ajax page, but what's probably true is ember-ajax is probably safer to use with the ember run loop. Admittedly my super old answer is still "correct", in that there is no built in communication layer, but the community etc has pushed toward ember-data, though I've often found it still easier to just use simple ajax calls when you don't have a large data ecosystem (and sure, why not with ember-ajax).